# Does meta_value (array) work with 'orderby'?

Tags: wp-query, array, meta-value

My goal here is to query posts by a meta_key, with the values falling in between 1-100. When pulled, it is suppose to be ordered by ascending starting from 1 to 100.

```
$post = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'category-1'
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'meta_key' => 'custom-key', 
        'meta_value' => array(1,100),
        'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
```

When looking at the page, it works of getting posts w/ meta-values '1-100', but it is not ordering correctly. It looks random (i.e. 1, 21, 5, 20, 6, 7, 8 , 3, 9, 19) saying in this order even when the page is constantly refreshed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Researching more, I got it to work with the following code

```
$post = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'category-1'
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'custom-key',
            'value' => array(1,100),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'custom-key',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC' 
);
```

Reference: http://www.wphub.com/use-meta_query-query-posts-postmeta/